# Python async MySQL lib for caching duplicate read queries in transaction

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Suppose I have web request handler in python which processes some complex logic using MySQL queries. I wrap request in some readable methods, for ex:

> START TRANSACTION
>
> get_some_users_in_range("select users where id>1 and id<24")
>
> get_user("select users where id=10")
>
> get_user("select users where id=10")
>
> get_user("select users where id=12")
>
> END TRANSACTION

All I want some smart caching application layer which understand what in context of transaction where is no need to do DB request after first query (because all needed rows already fetched by first query). Is where solutions for such problem in modern python (async preferable).

ps. raw SQL lib preferred (not ORM)

Comment: this is a primarily opinion based question, not meant for this site in particular, but it sounds like a good job for `redis` --> https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache

Comment: it is not async, it is ORM and it use redis, so need network interaction, i need something lighter in scope of python for one transaction only cache live time

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function with `functools.lru_cache`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Here is the async version of the same functionality: https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru

An excellent library that has more caching strategies (check their readme, they also have async support via separate lib): https://github.com/tkem/cachetools

But keep in mind that using such caching will work only in the scope of a single process. If you want the cache to be shared between processes/instances - consider some external cache service such as Redis for example